# (X - mu/stdev) per item in the column in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I'm trying to normalize (in the sense of `(X - mu)/stdev`) for each items in my column in Python. I have done so by creating the function:

```
def normalize(v):    
    for i in range (0, 2):
        for j in range (0, 220):
            (v[i][j] - np.mean(v[i])/np.std(v[i])

    return v[i][j]


But came up with the error:
  File "<ipython-input-247-aee77777412c>", line 6
    return v[i][j]
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have omitted a parenthesis in following line :

```
(v[i][j] - np.mean(v[i]))/np.std(v[i])
                        ^
```

Also since you didn't save the result of that line anywhere your function won't return a useful result.If you want to return the result of `(v[i][j] - np.mean(v[i])/np.std(v[i]))`

You can use `yield` in each iteration which makes your function return a generator.

```
def normalize(v):    
    for i in range (0, 2):
        for j in range (0, 220):
            yield (v[i][j] - np.mean(v[i]))/np.std(v[i])
```

Then you can loop over the generator like following :

```
for item in normalize(arg):
     # do stuff with item
```

Or convert the result to list using `list()` function (if it's not huge!).

```
list(normalize(arg))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `v` is a numpy array, you can massively speed up this calculation using vectorization and [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
def normalize(v):
    return (v - v.mean(1, keepdims=True)) / v.std(1, keepdims=True)
```